# How to get Label without htmlFor with Javasript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website that is loading a help desk form in an iFrame. There are 10 labels for 10 inputs. 8 of them have an htmlFor and a class of 'control-label'. One of them has an htmlFor with no class name. One has a class name of 'control-label' with no htmlFor.

I need to use JavaScript to grab the last label and add an htmlFor. However, I cannot grab it.

```
var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label')
```

This returns me an HTML Collection of 9 labels that all have htmlFor. It does not include the 10th label without the htmlFor. However, if I run:

```
console.log('Labels: ', labels);
```

This will show a list of 10 labels, but when I try to target the 10th label, it will return as undefined.

```
var controlLabels = document.getElementsByClassName('control-label')
```

This returns me an HTML Collection of 8 labels that all have htmlFor. It does not include the 9th label without the htmlFor.

```
var labels = [];
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName.length; i++) {
    labels.push(document.getElementsByTagName[i]);
}
```

This gets me an array of 9 objects, but again, not the label without the htmlFor.

```
var controlLabels = [];
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('control-label').length; i++) {
    controlLabels.push(document.getElementsByClassName('control-label')[i]);
}
```

This gets me an array of 8 labels, again without the label missing the htmlFor.

I need to get the last label, but when I run document.getElementsByX, it gets me an HTML Collection and not an array. How do I return an array of all the labels, and not an HTML Collection, so that I can target this label?

This is the exact line of code in the HTML:

```
<label class="control-label">Zip Code * </label>
```

Comment: Could you include the full HTML of your form? Also, are you trying to do this in an iframe? Also, what is the result of executing your query selector code inside a `setTimeout(() => {}, 1000)`? I'm wondering if maybe your field without the `for` is being loaded after the other fields.

Comment: Yes, the widget loads in an iFrame, although the code is injected at the bottom of the iFrame. Adding the setTimeout is fixing it now, as you are correct, the final label is being loaded after the other fields.

Comment: Oh good. I'll post an answer.

Comment: I posted an answer with a few solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be that the form element/label you're targeting is being loaded after the other elements. In order to determine if that is the case, you could try something like this:

```js
const labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label')
console.log("before", labels)

setTimeout(() => {
  const labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label')
  console.log("after", labels)
}, 1000)
```

If the extra label shows up in the `setTimeout`, then you'll know the label is being loaded after the others.

Just putting your code into a `setTimeout` is not a good longterm solution. The problem is that you don't know when the element will be added. So you will either wait too long to run your code, or not long enough.

An alternative is to use something like a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). You can use it to trigger an event when your form's DOM changes and then look for your labels. This code isn't tested, but something like this might work:

```js
const targetNode = document.getElementById('your-form-id');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    const labels = targetNode.querySelectorAll('label')

    // look for your label with a missing for attribute
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

If instead the issue is that your page hasn't fully loaded when you run your code, you could wait until the page's DOM is loaded to run your code:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label')
  console.log(labels)
});
```

If the element still isn't showing up, try listening for the `load` event instead of `DOMContentLoaded`.

In either case, you should make sure that your label will *always* be available when the document is loaded. If the third-party code is creating the element after the document is loaded, waiting for `load` or `DOMContentLoaded` will not reliably work. You would instead want to use a MutationObserver.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll` instead.

```js
_labels = document.querySelectorAll("label");
_labels.forEach(function(e) {
  console.log(e)
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="tet">
<label For="tet">test</label>
<label>testa</label>
<label class="control-label">Zip Code * </label>
```

Comment: This returns a NodeList of 9 objects, which are all the labels except for the one without the htmlFor.

Comment: @JasonBoyce as a test can you strip out JUST the labels from the HTML and run that in the snippet or a fiddle?

Comment: I created a jsfiddle with only 2 labels, one with an htmlFor and one without, and getElementsByTagName grabbed both and allowed me to grab the one without an htmlFor, so I don't know what's going on with the page I'm working on. I suspect it may be something to do with the fact that it generates the HTML from JavaScript on page load.

Answer (score 0):

There is no htmlFor attribute. There is a 'for' attribute you should place on an input's label element. browser and assistive technology then associate the label with the input.

For example you can tap a radio button's label to toggle the check state.

But it sounds like you need a CSS selector. So use the attribute selector syntax:

```
document.querySelector("[for='your-input-id']")
```

Comment: `htmlFor` is how you access the `for` attribute in JS, since `for` is a reserved word in JS. E.g. `el.htmlFor` (you cannot access it using `el.for`)

Comment: Also, the OP wants to get the element *without* a for attribute.

Comment: but you are selecting the elements using CSS selector syntax, not accessing the property value. Again, not an attribute. The property is mapped to htmlFor when you have the element as a variable in JS. But in your HTML it is 'for' and that is how you select it in CSS.

Comment: Yeah there is no ID and no 'for=""' so I am having trouble grabbing it. It will show up when I do a document.getElementsByTagName('label'), where it is included in the list, but not in the HTML Collection, so I cannot target it via the HTML Collection.

Comment: right, you are not specifying the attribute. You need to specify a for attribute and the value should map to the corresponding input's id. Otherwise you are just adding a custom attribute, which the selector syntax will work, but it does not add any semantic value.

Comment: The Label does not have a for attribute, and the input (which is not inside the label) does not have an id. So I need to grab a Label which does not have a for attribute, add the for attribute, and then later grab the input without an id and give it the same id. but the only attribute for the label I need to grab is a class name of 'control-label'. This is not my HTML (it's generated from javascript on a third-party server).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Cully for this tip.

```
function myFunction() {
    var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
    var label = labels[labels.length -1];
    label.htmlFor = "id_zipcode";
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(myFunction, 1000);
});
```

Adding the timeout is allowing the third-party JavaScript to finish generating the HTML and giving me a Label I can target with getElementsByTagName